# How does Black Body Radiation suggest the quantisation of energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I have read about Wein's Law and Rayleigh-Jeans Laws which were apparently based on classical mechanics and couldn't expalin the radiation spectrum of a black body.
Then Max Plank came up with the quantisation idea and was able to explain the phenomenon mathematically.

But, I dont seem to understand what does quantisation of energy has anything to do with this phenomenon in the first place?

I have seen equations, and they are real deal for sure, but can someone explain me how quantisation resolved the issue?
Im unable to make any connections whatsoever between the 'need of quantisation' and 'black body spectrum'.

Comment: Using the Rayleigh-Jeans formula the total emitted spectral power integrated from $\nu=0$ to $\nu=\infty$ is infinite for a blackbody at a finite temperature. Nobody knew how to resolve this problem until Planck came along.

Comment: have a read : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reconstruction (much simplified of course), of how Max Planck proceeded.

(Also, in retrospect it can be seen that Planck made a wrong attribution, but luckily for him it did not prevent him from arriving at a fruitful result.)

We have that the interior walls of the black body that is under examination are a particular temperature. The material of the walls is in a continuous process of emitting and absorbing electromagnetic radiation.

For the sake of thought experiment, consider the possibility that the material of the walls consists of a range of oscillators, each oscillator will oscillate at a *specific energy level*; not at any higher level, not at any lower level. We assume oscillators are present in a *continous spectrum* of energy levels.

For the sake of thought experiment, assume that these oscillators have the property that they cannot be energized in a cumulative process. Assume that in order to be energized at all the oscillator must go into its oscillating mode in a *single event*.

By contrast, if each oscillator can be energized in a cumulative process, then there is no upper bound. With cumulative process: *all* oscillators will accumulate energy.

If the energizing proces must be a single event then for the most demanding oscillators there is a reduced probability of being energized. The higher the energy demand, the lower the probability.

This line of reasoning (which, as mentioned, included a wrong attribution) allowed Planck to arrive at the equation that gives good fit with the data.

In retrospect:
It's not the material of the walls, but something about the transfer of energy between electromagnetic radiation and matter that gives rise to the observed equilibrium state.

The higher energy levels have a low probability of getting populated. The higher the corresponding energy, the lower the probability of the transfer event occuring.

For contrast: consider the concept of [communicating vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_vessels). Let's say you have a long row of communicating vessels, connected sequentially. You start filling at one end. Over time the fluid will keep filling more and more vessels. There is continuous accumulation.

The nature of energy transfer between electromagnetic radiation and matter is that that type of accumulation cannot occur. That is what gives rise to the observed black body spectrum

Hypothesis:
While Max Planck had embraced that *matter* consists of discrete units (atoms), at the time there was no reason for Planck to speculate that there can be something discrete about *electromagnetic radiation*. Presumably that is why Planck attributed the effect to some property of the material of the walls, rather than attributing it to electromagnetic radiation itself.

---

Later edit:
From the Hyperphysics website:
[Why does the Planck radiation curve fall below the classical Rayleigh-Jeans Law?](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod7.html)

> The classical view treats all electromagnetic modes of the cavity as equally likely because you can add an infinitesmal amount of energy to any mode. The quantum view expressed in the Planck hypothesis is that you either add the energy of a whole photon, or you don't add any at all. Since the excitation of a high frequency photon takes an energy high above the average thermal energy, it is therefore less likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot helping me, I have a trivial doubt. What am I supposed to imagine these 'hypothetical osscilators" as? I mean, are you talking about 'spring mass system' or something else? (just talking about the analogy)

Comment: @RohitShekhawat I recommend reading the other answer here (the answer by Sam Gallagher). The implementation details of the 'system of harmonic oscillators' are of no consequence to the validity of the reasoning, so those implementation details are never even considered. Stated differently: anything that is described by a law that is analogous to Hooke's law will do. The essential step is the supposition that the energy transfer process cannot occur in an accumulating form. The supposition is: the transfer of energy can only occur in one go.

Comment: Thanks again for replying in such detail. Can you confirm if Im right in saying "According to classical physics, when a blackbody is heated, its atoms will keep gaining more and more energy as the process goes on, hence most atoms will be at (very)high energy levels. Thus, the body will mostly radiate high frequency radiation as well. And thats where the experiments contradict" Is my line of thoughts correct or am I thinking totally irrelevant nonsense?

Comment: @RohitShekhawat It is stackexchange policy that the comment section is not for conversational interaction, and I endorse that policy. With your need to submit follow-up questions I recommend you take this question to a threaded forum, such as [physicsforums](physicsforums.com)

Answer (score 4):

It's important to point out before all else that Planck's derivation is not conclusive proof, in any sense, that energy must be quantized. But it is *consistent* with this hypothesis, and that's what is most interesting. Here's where things stand.

Before developing his own radiation law, Wien first developed the *displacement law* based on what may be called *Wien's theorem*. This is a classical theorem which requires no modification when entering into the quantum domain of problems. Wien's theorem states that the intensity of radiation in the range of wavelengths $\lambda$ to $\lambda+d\lambda$ has the form
$$
F(\lambda,T) = \lambda^{-5} \phi(T\lambda)
$$
where $\phi$ is some unknown function of the product $T\lambda$ only.

We can say that the goal of classical physicists studying black body radiation is to determine $\phi(T\lambda)$. Arguments for deriving this function are typically based around thermodynamic arguments, using the conservation of energy and momentum, and statistical thermodynamics. In some derivations, the *theorem of equipartition* is used, which assigns equal energy to each independent (and energetically accessible) degree of freedom of a system. As Jeans remarked in 1901 about applying the theorem of equipartition:

> If an interaction between matter and aether exists, no matter how small this interaction may be, the complete dynamical system will consist of the molecules of the gas, together with the aether, and must therefore be regarded as a system possessing an infinite number of degrees of freedom. Applying Boltzmann's Theorem [of equipartition] to this system, we are merely led to the conclusion that no steady state is possible until all the energy of the gas has been dissipated by radiation into the aether. This application of the theorem may or may not be legitimate, but it is, I think, certain that no other application is legitimate.

It's notable that Jeans was not a fan of equipartition, as seen in the last sentence, but he summarizes why the Rayleigh-Jeans law (and classical physics in general) requires the energy to increase infinitely.

To really understand Planck's derivation (which itself is somewhat inconsistent, mixing classical and quantum concepts), it would help to understand the previous attempts of Wien and Rayleigh. In a general sense, what we seek is a problem which depends on both temperature and wavelength in an absolute sense. For instance, in Wien's derivation, he considers a shrinking spherical cavity in thermal equilibrium. This idea originated with a thought experiment of Bartoli in the late 1800s. It's useful because it involves both radiation pressure (so that we have work performed, useful for demonstrating energy conservation) and the Doppler effect, as the radiation reflecting from the walls of the sphere is reflecting from a moving surface. The Doppler effect is in turn dependent on the wavelength of the radiation, and hence by thermodynamic analysis of this system we can enforce energy conservation and obtain useful results about the distribution of radiation intensity. In fact, this system was used to develop Wien's *theorem*, and Wien's *radiation law* follows by noting that a black body within the cavity is identical to an enclosed gas, which is amenable to the methods of the kinetic theory of gases, and with some further assumptions we get a result for $\phi$. (Which is only asymptotically correct.)

Wien points out in his works that *the function $\phi$ can only be determined by making hypotheses about the nature of matter and its interaction with the electromagnetic field*. Because the radiation emitted by excited elements is monochromatic, we know that, without reference to modern concepts of the atom, there must be periodic motion of a charged particle within an atom, so an alternative derivation to the above is to assume that the interaction between radiation and matter is *formally analogous* to the interaction between radiation and a system of harmonic oscillators. By a *formal analogy* is of course meant that between two systems, the dynamics of the systems are described by the same equations (e.g. mechanical systems and LCR circuits).

The insight of Planck, and the semi-classical derivation of Planck's law (and hence the introduction of the quanta of energy) is that the form of $\phi(T\lambda)$ is independent of the particular nature of the motion of the charged particles interacting with the electromagnetic field. Thus we may freely assume whatever convenient form for the material side of the matter-radiation exchange, so long as it displays periodic motion, and the thermodynamic arguments that follow will hold regardless of the particulars. This is what Planck did. And because he was a staunch opponent of the law of equipartition, and had a strong grasp of thermodynamics, his argument was developed around the concept of *entropy* and thus reads somewhat differently than previous attempts.

At this point, you're hopefully a bit more prepared to digest Cleonis's answer, and other papers on the topic. I'd recommend reading:
Passon, O., & Grebe-Ellis, J. (2017). Planck’s radiation law, the light quantum, and the prehistory of indistinguishability in the teaching of quantum mechanics. European Journal of Physics, 38(3), 1–14. https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-6404/aa6134.

---

**Further Reading.**

If you're interested in details of the derivations, the best reference is Whittaker's *History of Theories of the Aether and Electricity*, vol. 1, in the chapter on the classical theory of radiation, and vol. 2, on Planck's law. For a more direct treatment from first principles, see Born's *Atomic Physics*, and Bohm's *Quantum Theory*, which both go into detail. Keep in mind however that textbooks like these generally do not provide strictly rigorous derivations or air-tight reasoning, although they are very strict about applying various physical laws; many features of physics are taken for granted, objections are not raised so as to not confuse the reader, assumptions are not always so clearly laid out as they were in the original works. It's more about plausible reasoning, but that's usually enough when learning unless you're really digging at foundations.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. Indeed the general message should be: ideas from statistical mechanics (entropy, distribution of energy) can be applied in the physics of interaction between electromagnetic radiation and a population of harmonic oscillators; relations hold regardless of particulars. I'm reminded of the discussion by John Norton of Einstein's 1905 photo-electric effect article. The approach in Einstein's article is in terms of statistical mechanics. John Norton: [Einstein's Statistical Physics of 1905](https://sites.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/Goodies/Einstein_stat_1905/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that anyone had addresses the prime reason of what this radiation law given by Planck was highly regarded. The other laws which were equivalent to it are Maxwell-Boltzmann law, Wein's law and Fermi-Dirac law. Don't be surprised by name of Fermi-Dirac because it was known at that time but they didn't find it applicability and it gives least probability among all.

Maxwell-Boltzmann laws was used by Planck in derivation as a part but it also has not that much probability. Wein's law was very good or almost hit the board except at low frequencies which is quite normal for low temperature. Planck's law was though incorrect in its form but science people used it by changing parameters. It is constant and as lame as classical model was.

But good thing is that we got insight that there is upper limit on a system's energy. It means that $\varepsilon=N^2kT$ is approximation and by increasing number of constituents, one can't increase the energy of a system unlimited. It means by increasing number of particles, kinetic or total energy of a system has limit under given constraint or potential condition of a system.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "It is constant and as lame as classical model was." Presumably "It" refers to Planck's law, but what is meant by saying "It is constant"?

Comment: Average energy in Planck's law is $\varepsilon= \frac{h\nu_0}{e^{h\nu_0/kT}-1}$. Here $\nu_0$ is fundamental frequency so a constant, at thermal equilibirium so temperature is constant. Overall average energy is constant and dependent on temperature only similarly as in Rayleigh-Jeans model, $\varepsilon=kT$. So it is as unstable as classical model in present form, but it is being used dishonestly as having variable average energy.